# Duration of an iTunes sandbox subscription is not right for an IAP with free trial

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Duration of an iTunes sandbox subscription is not right for an IAP with free trial.
We have an auto renewal In App purchase product defined in iTunesConnect with a validity of 1 month. This has 1 month of free trial enabled.
According to Apple documentation, 1 month plan in sandbox mode is equivalent to 5 minutes. The plan should renew 6 times and expire.

So the time difference between the purchase date and the expiry date in the receipt should be 35 minutes(5 minutes x 6 times + 5 minutes x 1 time).
But the time difference in the sandbox receipt is 5 hours 36 minutes.

```
"original_purchase_date_pst":"2017-05-22 05:00:14 
"expires_date_pst":"2017-05-22 10:36:12

"purchase_date_ms":"1495454412000"
"expires_date_ms":"1495474572000"
```

Why there is a discrepancy when free trial is enabled ?

Even when we tested with a yearly subscription plan with two weeks free trial, it gives the same time difference(5 hours 36 minutes).

Comment: Did you learn any more about the issue?